# Actionscript 3 - parsing XML values

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following XML:

```
<document>
    <homeitems>
        <homeitem>
            <itemURL>URL1.html</itemURL>
        </homeitem>
        <homeitem>
             <itemURL>URL2.html</itemURL>
        </homeitem>
        <homeitem>
             <itemURL>URL3.html</itemURL>
             <itemImage>image3.jpg</itemImage>
        </homeitem>
    </homeitems>
</document>
```

And the following code that parses it:

```
var XMLData:XML = new XML(LoaderMax.getContent("xmlDoc")); // loads XML
var numitems = XMLData.homeitems.homeitem.length();

for (var i=0;i<numitems;i++) {
    if ((XMLData.homeitems.homeitem[i].itemImage) && (XMLData.homeitems.homeitem[i].itemImage!=="")) {
        trace("Loading image "+XMLData.homeitems.homeitem[i].itemImage);
    }
}
```

Trace result:

```
Loading image
Loading image
Loading image image3.jpg
```

WHY?!?!? Shouldn't it skip the items that don't have images? Am I stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that your test `if (XMLData.homeitems.homeitem[i].itemImage)` evaluate to true (just do a `trace(Boolean(XMLData.homeitems.homeitem[i].itemImage)` you will see true).

Also don't compare a node to a `String` use the `toString` method of the node or cast it explicitely to a `String` (i.e. `String(XMLData.homeitems.homeitem[i].itemImage)!=""` or `XMLData.homeitems.homeitem[i].itemImage.toString()!=""` )

There is multiple way todo it :

---

You can test if the node is undefined :

```
if (XMLData.homeitems.homeitem[i].itemImage != undefined)
```

---

Use hasOwnProperty method :

```
if (XMLData.homeitems.homeitem[i].hasOwnProperty('itemImage'))
```

---

And you can also cast your `itemImage` to a String and see if it's `!= ""` :

```
if (String(XMLData.homeitems.homeitem[i].itemImage) != "")
```

---

Using e4x and foreach you can have a cleaner code for your loop :

```
for each(var homeItem:XML in XMLData.homeitems.homeitem) {
    var itemImage:String = String(homeItem.itemImage)
    if (itemImage!="") {
        trace("Loading image "+itemImage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's enough if you compare with `!=` not `!==`

```
if ((XMLData.homeitems.homeitem[i].itemImage) && (XMLData.homeitems.homeitem[i].itemImage!="")) { 
    /* do somethong here */ 
}
```

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't change anything. Output is still the same

Comment: Try `XMLData.homeitems.homeitem[i].itemImage != NULL && XMLData.homeitems.homeitem[i].itemImage != ""`

Comment: 1120: Access of undefined property NULL, should have been lowercase null... but still no change - the conditional still evaluates as true